# image icon, list and random in java

Tags: java, image, list, data-structures, random

I have 4 pictures:

```
ImageIcon f1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\pic1.jpg");
ImageIcon f2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\pic2.jpg");
ImageIcon f3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\pic3.jpg");
ImageIcon f4 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\pic4.jpg");
Random r = new Random();
```

How can I put them into the list (or another data structure?) and **randomly** pick them one by one? I mean I pick for example f2, delete f2 in the list, them pick f4, delete f4 in the list... until all the elements are picked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put them into a list and call [`Collections.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) - then iterate over the list, which will be in a random order.